# laravel framework logs multiple errors

Tags: laravel, custom-error-handling

i recently bought a dating script .. but nobody responds to technical support to solve some bugs in the platform. Can you help me? I get the following errors in logs and I do not know whether it will affect me or will affect me along the way. Thank you!

```
[2017-10-01 20:44:34] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#20 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/app/Plugins/WebsocketChatPlugin/WebsocketServer/ServerConfigurationAutoloader.php(13): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/app/Plugins/WebsocketChatPlugin/WebsocketServer/Server.php(12): require_once('/home/webclasse...')
#23 {main}
```

In /home/webclasseu/webapps/interface/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter;
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '/pages/upload/image',
        '/plugin/upload/email/image',
        "testing/*",
        "paypal",
        "charge",
        "paymentwall_charge",
        "credits_callback",
        "superpower_callback",
        "superpower_charge"
    ];


    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $except_routes = \App\Components\Plugin::getCSRFRemoveRoutes();
        $this->except = array_merge($this->except, $except_routes);


        if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->shouldPassThrough($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request)) {
            return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
        }

        throw new TokenMismatchException;
    }


}
```

Comment: That doesn’t look like an “error”. Your code is throwing an exception if it fails the `if` logic check.

Comment: That is a laravel verification exception for the `csrf` token ! did you create a form ? or did you make an ajax call ??